# Is there any way to check the performance of mysql Indexing

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have assigned Indexes for my tables. Is there any way to identify the performance of my query? Thank you

**EDIT**
[image: EXPLAIN result]

Here i am attaching my test servers EXPLAIN result. In test server there are only few rows but in live server there are crores of records and it takes 10 to 15 minutes to execute query.
if its not visible here i am giving url for this image

***http://i45.tinypic.com/n6t8cx.jpg***

Comment: what do you mean with identify? do you want to know how much it improves? amount or percentage ?

Comment: I'm sure there's plenty of documentation out there on performance monitoring and tuning in mysql (PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA, EXPLAIN, etc).  What have you tried?

Comment: @kommradHomer because my project is using indexes but for some queries is taking more than 10 mins to execute. Its having many join queries and crores of records. so i want to know whats wrong in my query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following query will tell you whether query uses index or not:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT col1, col2, col3, COUNT(1) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE col1 = val 
GROUP BY col1 
ORDER BY col2;

SHOW WARNINGS;
```

You can add covering index for best performance.

For covering index you add columns used in where clauses first then columns used in group by the columns used in order by and then columns used in select.

e.g. for above query you can add covering index `KEY(col1, col2, col3)`

*Note Adding more indexes will slow down your insert queries.

Comment: possible_keys and keys are showing indexes which i have assigned. so that means its using indexes. Is there any condition will occur where the assigned indexes will not be effective? Is there any way to identify that ?

Comment: because my project is using indexes but for some queries is taking more than 10 mins to execute. Its having many join queries and crores of records

Comment: key shows its using which index and rows says how many rows its scanning also if Extra shows Using where, Using Index then is fastest

Comment: try doing explain for queries which are taking time. Also add composite covering index on columns used in join where group by order by and select clauses. Note: Adding indexes will slow down insert operations

Comment: @user007, why not show your EXPLAIN result in your question? It is using an index if key column is set and `Using where` is in extra column, however, it doesn't mean it's using the best index. `Using index` means the index is used to retrieve the data as well (covering index).

Comment: @Marcus Adams so you are telling if its not showing `using index`  i am not using the best index. By using best index i can reduce execution time

Comment: @Marcus Adams i have attached an url for the EXPLAIN result. pls check it and let me know whether i am using bad index. thank you...

Comment: @user007, there's nothing that will say you're using the "best index". MySQL tells you which index it's using and how it's using it. It's up to you decide the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can turn ON the slow-query-log, this might give additional information. Read this for more info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html