# How to manage huge DB tables to minimize fetching time in MySql

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, partitioning

I have a huge Database table containing around 5 Million rows. Now retrieving records make the server slow in some cases. How can i manage the table now as it growing over the days.

I was thinking to make some archiving technique on yearly basis for example breakdown the complete tables into many small tables on yearly basis, but that cost me a lot of changes in coding. I have to change the complete structure of querying from database. So, most probably changes on most of the places in project.

What else i can do to reduce fetching time of records from database tables? Is there any other technique that i can adopt to avoid many changes in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Five million rows is somewhere between "medium" and "large" in terms of size. "Huge" is over a billion rows. Seriously.  It's hard to answer this question without more information about what you're trying to fetch, and how often.

Comment: Focus your efforts on ensuring your queries are optimised. If you're still having problems after that then look at splitting or archiving old data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily [PARITION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-types.html) the table horizontally using `PARITION BY RANGE` in MySQL.

Also if you have many columns in table then you can break that table into two or more tables by Vertical partitioning method.

Also add proper indexes preferably clustered or [covering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578241/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-performance-of-mysql-indexing/11578264#11578264) indexes on tables and test queries for performance by using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html).

Answer (score 1):

May be table partitioning will help in that case. The following provide the info :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19313/partitioning-a-table-will-boost-the-performance