# Mysql- Indexing on inner join condition

Tags: mysql, indexing, inner-join

I have 2 tables like below

```
inv_ps
--------
inv_fkid  ps_fkid
1         2
1         4
1         5

other_table
----------
id   ps_fkid  amt  other_data
1     2       20   xxx
2     NULL    10   xxx
3     NULL    5    xxx 
4     5       6    xxx
5     4       7    xxxx
```

and here's the query

```
SELECT inv_ps.ps_fkid, ot.amt FROM invoice_ps inv_ps INNER JOIN other_table ot ON ot.ps_fkid = inv_ps.ps_fkid WHERE inv_ps.inv_fkid=1 GROUP BY inv_ps.ps_fkid
```

this does works fine, however when i view EXPLAIN Sql

```
id  select_type       table     type        possible_keys       key        key_len      ref         rows        Extra
1   SIMPLE           inv_ps     ref         inv_fkid,ps_fkid    inv_fkid      4     const            1            Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE            ot        ref         ps_fkid             ps_fkid       5     inv_ps.ps_fkid  3227       Using where
```

This supposed to scan only 3 rows but why it is searching in 3227 rows even though i added indexes on both join columns ? is it because the column **ot.ps_fkid** was set to **NULL**?

Please explain

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge index is used in `GROUP BY` clause only if it is a [covering index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578241/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-performance-of-mysql-indexing/11578264#11578264)

try explain with following `covering indexs` on tables:

```
ALTER TABLE other_table ADD INDEX ix1 (ps_fkid, amt);
ALTER TABLE invoice_ps ADD INDEX ix1 (inv_fkid, ps_fkid);

SELECT a.ps_fkid, b.amt
FROM  (SELECT ps_fkid
       FROM invoice_ps
       WHERE inv_fkid = 1
       GROUP BY ps_fkid
      )a
      INNER JOIN other_table b
         ON a.ps_fkid = b.ps_fkid;
```

Comment: just added those indexes but the row count still the same

Comment: keep indexes as it is and try new updated query. It should give you better permanence.