# Very slow query when using ORDER BY and LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

The following query takes 10 seconds to finish when having order by. Without order by it finish in 0.0005 seconds. I am already having an index on field "sku", "vid" AND "timestamp". I have more 200,000 record in this table. Please help, what is wrong with the query when using order by.

```
SELECT i.pn,i.sku,i.title, fl.f_inserted,fl.f_special, fl.f_notinserted
FROM inventory i 
LEFT JOIN inventory_flags fl ON fl.sku = i.sku AND fl.vid = i.vid
WHERE i.qty >=2 ORDER BY i.timestamp  LIMIT 0,100;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `inventory`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pn` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `sku` (`sku`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `inventory_flags`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory_flags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_inserted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_notinserted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_special` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sku` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `sku` (`sku`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**EXPLANE RESULT:**

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  fl  system  vid,sku NULL    NULL    NULL    0   const row not found
1   SIMPLE  i   index   NULL    timestamp   5   NULL    10  Using where
```

Comment: Remember to analyze different solutions with EXPLAIN.

Comment: You have 200K records in the table and the create table shows `AUTO_INCREMENT=115`. How is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding seprate indexes on columns you need to put [multicolumn index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on tables as you are using more than one columns from same table in joining condition.

after including columns from `WHERE` clause also include columns used in `ORDER BY` clause in [composite index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578241/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-performance-of-mysql-indexing/11578264#11578264).
try adding flowing indexes and test them using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html):

```
ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX ix_if inventory_flags(sku, vid);
ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX ix_i inventory(sku, qty, timestamp);
```

also try to avoid `DISTINCT` clause in your query, it is equivalent to `GROUP BY` clause, if you still need it then consider adding covering index.

Answer (score 2):

If `sku` is unique to each inventory item then define it as `UNIQUE` - it'll speed things up. (Or the combination of `sku` and `vid` - define a composite index in that case.)

Why are you doing `SELECT DISTINCT`? The vast majority of the time using `DISTINCT` is a sign that your query or your table structure is wrong.

Since it's `DISTINCT`, and `sku` is not `UNIQUE` it can't use the index on timestamp to speed things up, so it has to sort a table with 200,000 records - it can't even use an index on qty to speed that part up.

PS. Omesh has some good advice as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `force index(index_key)`. try it, and you will see in explain query that mysql now will use the key index when 'order by'