# Optimize query on single table with group by, where, and 'flag'

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am struggling with the performance of type of query that I am using repeatedly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following table:

```
    item week type  flag   value
    1    1    5     0      0.93 
    1    1    12    1      0.58 
    1    1    12    0      0.92 
    1    2    6     0      0.47 
    1    2    5     0      0.71 
    1    2    5     1      0.22
    ...  ...  ...   ...    ...
```

(the complete table has about 10k different items, 200 weeks, 1k types. flag is 0 or 1. Around 20M rows in total)

I would like to optimize the following query:

```
    select item, week, 
    sum(value) as total_value,
    sum(value * (1-least(flag, 1))) as unflagged_value
    from test_table 
    where type in (5,10,14,22,114,116,121,123,124,2358,2363,2381) 
    group by item, week;
```

Currently, the fastest I could get was with an index on (type, item, week) and engine = MyIsam.
(I am using mysql on a standard desktop).

Do you have any suggestions (indices, reformulation, etc.) ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `sum(value * (1-least(flag, 1))) `? Is the `least` necessary?

Comment: agreed with podiluska ... if flag has only 0 and 1 value, then value*( 1- flag) should do the trick of summing up values when flag is zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as per my knowledge `GROUP BY` query can be fully optimized only with [covering index.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578241/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-performance-of-mysql-indexing/11578264#11578264)

add following `covering index` on your table and check with `EXPLAIN`:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table  ADD KEY ix1 (type, item, week, value, flag);
```

after adding index check following query with `EXPLAIN`:

```
SELECT type, item, week,
    SUM(value) AS total_value,
    SUM(IF(flag = 1, value, 0)) AS unflagged_value
FROM test_table
WHERE type IN(5,10,14,22,114,116,121,123,124,2358,2363,2381)
GROUP BY type, item, week;
```

you may need to modify your query like this:

```
SELECT item, week,
       SUM(total_value) AS total_value,
       SUM(unflagged_value) AS unflagged_value
FROM(
    SELECT type, item, week,
        SUM(value) AS total_value,
        SUM(IF(flag = 1, value, 0)) AS unflagged_value
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY type, item, week
)a
WHERE type IN(5,10,14,22,114,116,121,123,124,2358,2363,2381)
GROUP BY item, week;
```

see query execution plan. [SQLFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfad9/1)

Comment: I didn't know the concept of `covering index`. I makes it amazingly faster !! Thanks! And the first query you mention is even faster than my original. Your second query is slow though (on my data).

Comment: you`re welcome! ya first query would be faster, As `EXPLAIN` says `USING WHERE, USING INDEX`. I thought first query might not use index properly because of `IN` clause, that's why posted alternate query also.

Comment: @cafe876: Try also this index: `(item, week, type, value, flag)`

Answer (score 0):

I think You should have only two indices in the table

```
1. An index on type (non clustered)
2. A composite index on (item, week) in the same order (non clustered)
```