# Mysql - Range query and sort

Tags: mysql

For the next query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.body, m.poster, m.added 
   FROM messages m
   WHERE  ((m.poster_id = '11' OR m.poster_id = '22') AND (m.to = '11' OR m.to = '22'))
   ORDER BY m.id DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

What are the best indexes?

I've tried (poster_id, to, id) - about 1.5s
Tried (poster_id, to) - about 0,10s

If i remove the order i get 0.00s

The thing is that even on empty results, with the ORDER BY, i still get 0,09s.

The explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                | key             | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | range | posterid_to_idx,to,poster_id | posterid_to_idx | 8       | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to simplify your query,

```
SELECT m.id, m.body, m.poster, m.added 
FROM messages m
WHERE  m.poster_id IN ('11', '22') AND 
       m.to = IN ('11', '22')
ORDER BY m.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

add index on `m.id` (*alone*), `m.poster_id`, and `m.to`

Comment: Tried that ... its the same or even worse some times

Answer (score 0):

You may need to re-write your query using `IN` clause:

```
SELECT m.id, m.body, m.poster, m.added 
FROM messages m
WHERE  m.poster_id IN(11, 22) AND 
        m.to IN(11, 22)
ORDER BY m.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Add following [Covering Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578241/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-performance-of-mysql-indexing/11578264#11578264) for the best performance:

```
ALTER TABLE messages  ADD KEY ix1(poster_id, to, id, body, poster, added)
```

For fast inserts you may try normal index:

```
ALTER TABLE messages  ADD KEY ix1(poster_id, to, id);
```

Comment: I already said that i tried the (poster_id, to, id). Also adding a index on all that columns its impossible since body its text

Comment: I can't think of any other solution, in extra `Using where; Using filesort`. Ideally it should be only `Using where;`

Comment: I know, but i need to get the last rows from the messages table :)

Comment: Can you try `EXPLAIN` with this new `IN` clause query, as `IN` performs better than `OR` clause.