# order by using filesort on indexed field

Tags: mysql

I have a problem where my query is `Using filesort`, even though the field is indexed.

This is my query:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT u.name, u.surname, u.id
FROM rw_users u
ORDER BY u.created DESC
LIMIT 4
```

This is the output:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra           
1   SIMPLE       u      ALL                                     9     Using filesort
```

This is `create table`:

```
CREATE TABLE `rw_users` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `premium` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'level or premium membership (0 = standard)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `password` (`password`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `premuim` (`premium`),
  KEY `name_surname` (`name`,`surname`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_rw_users` FOREIGN KEY (`premium`) REFERENCES `rw_premium` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci
```

What do I need to do to get rid of `Using filesort`? I tested on database (exactly the same table) with 118 rows and it still gives me `Using filesort`, so it can't use it because its faster than using index.

Comment: Where you know from that using the index is faster than filesort for only 118 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the best performance for select queries add [covering index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578241/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-performance-of-mysql-indexing/11578264#11578264). See [here](http://www.mysqlconf.com/mysql2009/public/schedule/detail/6796):

```
ALTER TABLE rw_users ADD KEY ix1 (created, name, surname, id);
```

for `INNODB` engine you don't need to include `id` in index, check both indexes with `EXPLAIN`.

```
ALTER TABLE rw_users ADD KEY ix1 (created, name, surname);
```