# Left join between a small and a very large table in mysql

Tags: mysql, left-join, indexing

I have two tables; one has 50 records and contains some city names and the other has 3173958 records and has city to country code info:

```
+---------+-----------+
| country | city      |
+---------+-----------+
| gb      | sapiston  |
| gb      | sapperton |
| gb      | sarclet   |
| gb      | sarnau    |
| gb      | sarnau    |
+---------+-----------+
```

The large table is indexed on `city` field but this query takes about **5 minutes** to execute:

```
SELECT small.* , c2c.country FROM small LEFT JOIN c2c ON ( lower( small.city ) = lower( c2c.city ) );
```

What is the problem?
How can I make it faster?

Comment: Have you created INDEX on city columns? It will make your SELECT statement a lot faster but consequently your INSERT and UPDATE operations will deteriorate.

Comment: @JonasT: in `c2c` table (the large one), yes!

Comment: When you use functions on columns inside WHERE, the indexes cannot be used. Find a way to avoid using LOWER.

Comment: How long does it take to run this, "SELECT small.* , c2c.country FROM small,c2c
WHERE ( lower( small.city ) = lower( c2c.city ) );"? I strongly suggest you to use integer column in c2c to join small.

Comment: @JonasT: 52 secs ! but i'm searching for country code of cities ! which integer? both are texts!

Comment: Do you have integer ID column in small table? Add foreign key column in c2c table, update foreign key values in c2c city table and join using those integer columns. string function LOWER makes your execution time a lot slower too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make use of index you should store `city` values in lower format wither in same column or in different indexed column because, applying lower function in query can not make use of index.

```
SELECT small.* , c2c.country 
FROM small 
     LEFT JOIN c2c 
         ON small.city = c2c.city;
```

Also add following index and [covering index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578241/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-performance-of-mysql-indexing/11578264#11578264) on table for better performance:

```
ALTER TABLE small ADD KEY ix1(city);
ALTER TABLE c2c ADD KEY ix1(city, country);
```

After adding above indexes check query execution plan using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)

Comment: @4r1y4n What is the execution with this solution? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a function on column names inside WHERE clause, the indexes cannot be used; because MySQL has to get the computed value for all rows before it can do a comparison. The equality comparisons are usually case-insensitive (depending on column collations) so you can safely omit the LOWER function. Here is the revised query:

```
SELECT small.*, c2c.country
FROM small
LEFT JOIN c2c ON small.city = c2c.city
```

Next, you should add a covering index on `c2c`. The index should be made on `(city, country)`. This way MySQL won't have to look at the table to retrieve the country names. It will look at the index while joining `city` and at the same time it can fetch `country` column from the same index.

Next, change `small.*` to only the columns you need.

Next, create an index on `small.city` if you have not done that already -- or -- if you find that you only need two/three columns from the `small` table then create a covering index instead. E.g. if you are selecting `small.somecolumn` (and using `small.city` in WHERE/ON clause) create an index for `(city, somecolumn)`.

Last, make sure that the `city` column in both tables is same data-type, length, and most importantly, collation. When collation is different, MySQL has to convert the collations before comparing which could slow down your query.